# How to store javascript coordinates to database through ruby on rails (Geolocation, HTML5, Javascript, Ruby On Rails)

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, html, geolocation, coordinates

Please help if you can!

I've been looking all over the net trying to find a clear explanation on how to pass a javascript variable (from .js file) to the controller and display it on the views page (erb.html file). 
So far this is a piece of what I have:

**.js file:**
    var lat = position.coords.latitude;
    var lon = position.coords.longitude;

```
$.ajax({
type: "GET",
url: "/locations/show",
data: { latitude: lat, longitude: lon } 
});
```

**controller.rb file**
    class LocationsController < ApplicationController

```
def index

@lat = params[:latitude]
@long = params[:longitude]

//these print statements below display the collect variables in the console
print "this is lat: #{@lat}"
print "this is long: #{@long}"
end
```

**view.erb.html**

```
//the @lat & @long variables are now nil and don't display at all.
//but in the console they display the collect values.
this is lat: <%= @lat %>
this is long: <%= @long %>
```

I'M CONFUSED!!!  PLEASE HELP! THANK YOU!!!!!

Comment: Far too broad a question for this site. Choices are update a form that gets submitted or send data via ajax. Both approaches should be easy to research on the web.